# What means "distributed" in NoSQL definition?

Tags: nosql

> NoSQL DEFINITION: Next Generation Databases mostly addressing some of
>   the points: being non-relational, *distributed*, open-source and
>   horizontally scalable.

Is horizontally scalable the same thing(or include) distributed? If not, what it means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NoSQL systems employ a **distributed architecture**, with the data held in a redundant manner on several servers. In this way, the system can easily scale out by adding more servers, and failure of a server can be tolerated.

**Horizontal scalability** is the ability to increase the speed or availability of the server by adding more servers, typically using clustering and load balancing.

**So yes both are similar terms.  horizontal scalability increases the distributed architecture.**

**data replication** if the same data is stored on multiple storage devices

**SCHEMA FREE:**  In Oracle you would define your table structure first and then insert/delete your data but thats not the case with Schema free.No schema migrations. your code defines your schema. So no more Alter table statements.

Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL

http://searchcio.techtarget.com/definition/horizontal-scalability

Comment: What's the difference? (please, in simple terms)

Comment: What's the difference between distributed, horizontally scalable and easy replication support? http://nosql-database.org/

Comment: thank you for accepting my answer. I know these terms are bit confusing at first. From architecture point of view distributed , horizontal scalability, data replication are important whereas from developer's point of view Schema free is important term.